# F# join with IQueryable

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I am experimenting with using F# query expression to retrieve data from database. 
For the following code:

```
1   let q = query{
2       for i in dataContext.Incident do
3       select i
4   }
5   
6   let q2 = query{
7       for i in dataContext.Incident do
8       select i
9   }
10  
11  let q3 = query{
12      for i in q do
13      join i2 in q2
14      on(i.IncidentId = i2.IncidentId)
15      select i
17  }
```

I am getting error as Incorrect syntax for join at line 13.

Are there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try moving the contents of line 14 to line 13, so that both are on the same line.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do you want to put an an answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# being a whitespace-sensitive language, this is just an indentation issue; either of the following should work:

```
let q3 = query {
    for i in q do
    join i2 in q2 on (i.IncidentId = i2.IncidentId)
    select i
}

let q3' = query {
    for i in q do
    join i2 in q2 on
        (i.IncidentId = i2.IncidentId)
    select i
}
```